# Why my datatable is not populating using *ngFor in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 5 and As I'm making my custom table component so I get started from basics. But I don't know whats going wrong with my code and why I'm not getting my datatable populated with my data? Here is my code

**app.component.html**

```
<input #searchbox placeholder="Search Something" (input)="onSearching($event.target.value)">
<br>
<h1>Results</h1>
<br>
<table width="100%" style="border: 2px solid black;">
  <tr *ngFor="let xyz of getFilteredData">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i=index;">
      {{ xyz[i] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  {{rows}}
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  columns:string[];
  posts: students[];
  getFilteredData: students[];
  rows: number = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = ['UserId','ID','Title','Body'];
  }

  constructor() {
    this.posts = [
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 2,
        id: 2,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 3,
        id: 3,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 4,
        id: 4,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 5,
        id: 5,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 6,
        id: 6,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 7,
        id: 7,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      },
      {
        userId: 8,
        id: 8,
        title: 'Ahmer',
        body: 'Loreum ispum dore.'
      }
    ];

    this.getFilteredData = this.posts;
  }
  title = 'app';


  onSearching(searchValue: string) {
    console.log(this.posts)
    this.getFilteredData = this.posts.filter(
      d => d.body.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()));

    this.rows = this.getFilteredData.length;
  }
}

class students {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

**Here is my output when my app loaded**

[image]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I populate my data in datatable using `*ngFor` in angular?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. So, `UserId` != `userId`. Change the casing in the columns list strings to match that of the data property names, and this might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in order to get this to work.

Changed the case of the column names to match that of the fields in the data.

```
this.columns = ['userId', 'id', 'title', 'body'];
```

Then, I changed the template to use the `col` variable rather than the index (`i`) that you were using.

```
<table width="100%" style="border: 2px solid black;">
  <tr *ngFor="let xyz of getFilteredData">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{ xyz[col] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After that I got a table with 8 rows and 4 columns; all the data displayed.

Comment: Superb. Thanks for your precious time.